# get days part from a date interval

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I want to get day parts from a date interval. 
For example I have a date interval 21/12/2013 to 28/12/2013. 
Now I want to get all day part from this interval like as 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28.

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *date_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",from_date];
NSLog(@"%@",date_str);
NSString *date_str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",to_date];
NSLog(@"%@",date_str1);
NSDate *starting_date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date_str];
NSDate *end_date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date_str1];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:starting_date toDate:end_date options:0];
NSInteger days = [components day];
```

That code giving total no of days.

How can i get this output?

Thanks

Comment: what are from_date and to_date?

Comment: Why do you make double date-string-date conversion? To get array of days you need for-cycle to iterate from the first day to last day. But you need to take into account transitions from one month to another (and maybe years)

Comment: You could create a method (in a NSDate category maybe) that add a day to a date, and iterate since you know the date differences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from your code and assuming,

```
NSString *date_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"December 21, 2013"];
NSString *date_str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"December 28, 2013"];
```

If you need it within the same month, it can be in this way,

```
NSDateComponents *component1 = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:starting_date];
NSDateComponents *component2 = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:end_date];

    for (int i = component1.day; i <= component2.day; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%i", i);
    }
```

But if your dates expand between different months, then you have to add checking for month components in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I will continue on your code, with some dirty code of mine, but it gets the job done if what you provided is your date format:

```
NSArray *begining_day = [date_str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSMutableArray *part_days = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {

 [part_days addObject:([begining_day[0] integerValue] + i)];

}
```

Now part_days will have your days, BUT! You have to handle the end of each month.

I'm 100% sure you'll find better solutions, but I thought I could share the first thing I thought of, you might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1/12/14",@"2/12/14",@"3/12/14",@"4/12/14",@"5/12/14", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSArray *myArray = [[array objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    [dayArray addObject:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];

}
NSLog(@"%@",dayArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can incrementally add 24 hours to your startDate until you pass your endDate. Using NSDateComponents you can pick out the day. Instead of logging them with NSLog just store them in a string or array.

```
NSDate *startDate   = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:300000000];
NSDate *endDate     = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:302000000];

for (NSDate *nextDate = startDate; [nextDate compare:endDate] < 0; nextDate = [nextDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:24*60*60] ) {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:nextDate];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSLog(@"day %li", (long)day);
}
```